# How to resolve promise on boolean change?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to achieve the following:

1. Add an EventListener to a button, and on-click it will change the global variable `isClicked` to true
2. When `isClicked` is set to True, run `return getCheckedBoxes("checkboxes");` which just gets which checkboxes have been checked

That's all! The issue is that I'm calling this script from a Python script, so I need to make use of `await` to block the Python script from running. I don't know much JS, but I've managed to do the following:

```
var isClicked = false;

document.getElementById("btn-id").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "none";
    isClicked = true;
});

function getCheckedBoxes(checkboxName) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(checkboxName);
    var checkboxesChecked = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            checkboxesChecked.push(Number(checkboxes[i].id));
        }
    }

    return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : null;
};

let promise = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (isClicked == true)
    resolve(promise)
});

return getCheckedBoxes("checkboxes");
```

The script stops on the `let promise = ...` line, which is a good sign. But I don't know how to resolve the promise when `isClicked` becomes set to true, so that the rest of the script can (i.e so I can run `return getCheckedBoxes("checkboxes");`).

Comment: What is to stop you from calling `getCheckedBoxes` from within the click handler?

Comment: @redouglas Like I said, I'm running the script from another Python script that essentially does this: `checkedBoxes = runJS(<above code>)`. If I just had a return line in the click handler, the python script won't record the output! So I have to "block" the script from running using await & promises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you're looking for is an inconvenient one. Instead of resolving a promise on boolean change, you could resolve the promise when the callback is called.

This answer does assume that the code placed in an `async function`. Note that a return value of an `async function` will always be a new promise.

```
// the line below waits until the click callback is called
await new Promise(resolve => {
  document.getElementById("btn-id").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "none";
    resolve();
  });
});

var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(checkboxName);
var checkboxesChecked = [];

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        checkboxesChecked.push(Number(checkboxes[i].id));
    }
}

return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only do `await` in an async function, make sure you run it there.
And you are checking if isClicked is true once, so the promise will never be resolved.

```
async function submitBox() {
    var submit;
    
    document.getElementById("btn-id").addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "none";
        submit();
    });
    
    function getCheckedBoxes(checkboxName) {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(checkboxName);
        var checkboxesChecked = [];
    
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                checkboxesChecked.push(Number(checkboxes[i].id));
            }
        }
    
        return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : null;
    };
    
    let promise = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        submit = resolve;
    });
    
    return getCheckedBoxes("checkboxes");
}
```